# Cannot convert a markdown file to PDF in WSL environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

error message

[image: 1]

In the wsl environment, markdown files cannot be converted to pdf files;but it can be converted before installing wsl environment.

Comment: Could you please link to the vscode extension that you are using. Along with a minimal markdown file that you expect to work. Thanks

Comment: Yes,I can.But I don not know why it doesn't work.